# Elementary Number Theory (Least Residue)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the least residue modulo 7 of the quantity $(22 \times 51
) + 698^5$.

What I did was as follows:

I know $22 \equiv 1 $ (mod 7), $51\equiv 2$ (mod 7) and that $698 \equiv 5\equiv -2$ (mod 7).

So,

$22 \times 51 + 698^5 \equiv (1 \times 2) + (-2)^5\equiv -30 \equiv -2$ mod 7.

Thus the least residue modulo 7 is -2.

I want to know if my thinking process is correct and also can the least residue modulo be 5?

Comment: The process looks good! Technically $5$ is the lowest residue since we take nonnegative numbers for the residue classes (but $5=-2$ so it's the same thing).

Comment: One assumes when the say "least" they mean "least non-negative".  Other wise I can clam $-9, -16, -25,.... -461258866525, -461258866532,...$ are all less.  So, yes, the answer is $5\mod 7$ which is equivalent to $-2 \mod 7$.

Comment: ...or maybe they don't and they mean least absolute valued residue.  I guess it's a matter as to whether their standard residue class is represented as $0,......, -n$ or $-\lceil \frac {n}2\rceil + 1,....,0,...\lfloor \frac {n}2\rfloor$.  Anyway, your calculation was perfect.  And $-2 \equiv5 \mod 7$.  I'd personally claim least means $5$ but ... well, credit where credit is due and what's the important thing?  I'd give full marks.  (Actually I'd be more specific in what I wanted as an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct and

$$(22 \times 51) + 698^5\equiv-2 \pmod 7$$

$$(22 \times 51) + 698^5\equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

are equivalent.

In some cases, for convenience, we can fix and use $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ as residue classes $\pmod 7$ in other cases we can fix $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ but they are obviously equivalent choices.